# Why I can't call a function in the class?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

```
class Editor():
def __init__(self):
    self=Tkinter.Tk()
    EditedSongName=StringVar()
    EditedArtistName=StringVar()
    SongNameLabel = Label(self, text="Song Name:")
    SongNameLabel.pack()
    SongNameEntry = Entry( self,textvariable=EditedSongName)
    SongNameEntry.pack()
    ArtistNameLabel = Label(self, text="Artist Name:")
    ArtistNameLabel.pack()
    ArtistNameEntry = Entry( self,textvariable=EditedArtistName)
    ArtistNameEntry.pack()
    EditOkButton = Button( self, text="Ok", command=EditOk )
    EditOkButton.pack(anchor=CENTER)
    self.mainloop()

def EditOk(self):
    print "RSAOJ"
    Root.canvas.delete(SongName)
    SongName=canvas.create_text(650,30,text = EditedSongName,fill = 'black',font=("Times New Roman",35)    )
    canvas.pack()
    Root.canvas.delete(ArtistName)    
    ArtistName=canvas.create_text(650,90,text = EditedArtistName,fill = 'black',font=("Times New Roman",20)    )
    canvas.pack()
    self.destroy()
```

No matter how i change the function, there is always an error.
NameError: global name 'EditOk' is not defined
What is that suppose to mean? I still can't get the concept of classes and selfs.

Comment: 1. Fix your indentation, 2. `self.EditOk`

Comment: `self=Tkinter.Tk()` - what do you think you're doing there?

Comment: I use self.EditOk still won't work, 
AttributeError: EditOk.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
EditOkButton = Button( self, text="Ok", command=self.EditOk )
```

Rather than

```
EditOkButton = Button( self, text="Ok", command=EditOk )
```

the method is only defined for a particular instance

Comment: There's no more error but the window doesn't show up. Why?